# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm new to Spring. I was following some tutorial to make a simple insert operation using Hibernate & Spring. However it ended up in some errors, I'm not able to understand the exact issue in this one. My code

### Applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

    <property name="annotatedClasses">  
        <list>  
            <value>com.hib.model.MailHib</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>  

    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="d" class="com.dao.MailDaoCls">  
<property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>  


</beans>
```

### MailDaoCls

```
package com.dao;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import com.bo.model.Mail;
import com.hib.model.MailHib;

public class MailDaoCls {
    HibernateTemplate template;  
    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
    }  
    //method to save employee  
    public void saveEmployee(MailHib e){  
        template.save(e);  
    } 

}
```

### My logic

```
        Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

    MailDaoCls dao=(MailDaoCls)factory.getBean("d");

    MailHib mail = new MailHib();
    //mail.setMailId(1);
    mail.setFrmEMail("ffff");
    mail.setToEMail("ssss");
    mail.setSubjectEMail("fffffsf");
    mail.setMessage("messagssse");
    dao.saveEmployee(mail);
```

Error it throws is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
 bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 
 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' 
 while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find 
class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

**UPDATE**
after adding the commons-dbcp the error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean   with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at com.dao.impl.MailDaoImpl.main(MailDaoImpl.java:59)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
```

Comment: Why are you even creating a context (or `BeanFactory`) yourself... You shouldn't be doing that you should use dependency injection instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I was following this tutorial http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration

Answer (score 0):

See this part of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

Looks like you miss the commons-dbcp.jar in your classpath.

Add the dependency:

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

**Update:**
The second exception occured because `org.springframework.jdbc<Version>.jar` is missing

Comment: Let me check and get back to you Jens

Comment: @Syed you are sure you get exactly the same error? Can you add the stacktrace as an update to your question please?

Comment: yes, the error is still same. Updated the stacktrace. Please check it.

Comment: @Syed I is not the same: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
`

Comment: sorry jens, I had just seen the sample.. WHat should be done for this fix?

Comment: @Syes Add the <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>YourSpringVersion</version>
</dependency> as a dependency to your pom. And all other missing dependencies

Comment: Let me check and get back to you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114505/discussion-between-syed-and-jens).